# How to use a #define inside a C include statement?

Tags: c, include, preprocessor

I have a header file that selects between two platforms:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _WINDOWS
#define PAR_CLASS           TestPar
#define PAR_INCLUDE_FILE    "TestPar.h"
#else
#define PAR_CLASS           Par
#define PAR_INCLUDE_FILE    "Par.h" 
#endif
```

With this I can use the following line to include a header file:

```
#include "ClassNames.h" 

#include PAR_INCLUDE_FILE
```

However, I expect more classes and for the PAR_CLASS and PAR_INCLUDE_FILE, the only different is the " and the .h
What I would like is to use the PAR_CLASS inside the `#include`, something like:

```
#include "PAR_CLASS.h"
```

But this does not work... Is something like this possible?

I want it to work in both Visual Studio (2019) and Arduino IDE.

Comment: Maybe token pasting? `#include PAR_CLASS ## ".h"`?

Comment: @barmar: you can't use token pasting to do string literal concatenation, and you can't use string literal concatenation in a preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement it using the following macro structure:

```
#define stringify(x) #x
#define GEN_INC_PATH(a) stringify(a.h)

#include GEN_INC_PATH(PAR_CLASS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the `#include` statements inside the logic? Something like

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#include "TestPar.h"
#else
#include "Par.h" 
#endif
```

and move the `#define` into their respective include files

Comment: Because I do not want to put all these conditional include in all files I need the include files for.

Comment: Why would you put it in lots of files? You put it in one include file and include that

Comment: Not in a lot, but all files that needs to include a certain header file (which can add up quite a bit for a bigger program).